# Calculating the sum of a imported table

Tags: python

This is the content of my text file:

```
nummer naam vak1 vak2 vak3 vak4 vak5
1234567 Jan 5 7 0 6 4
3526435 Marie 5 5 7 0 0
2230431 Kees 6 10 0 8 6
7685433 André 4 7 8 7 5
0364678 Antoinette 0 2 8 8 8
1424354 Jerôme 7 9 0 5 0
4536576 Kamal 8 0 8 7 8
1256033 Diana 0 0 0 0 0
5504657 Petra 6 6 7 0 6
9676575 Malika 0 6 0 0 8
0253756 Samira 3 8 6 7 10
```

I have imported the list and I am able to open and print the results into python but that's it. Below is my code for the same:

```
results = open("resultaten.txt","r")    
Empty_str = ''                          

line = results.readline()               

while line != Empty_str:               
    print(line.strip('\n'))             
    line = results.readline()           

results.close()
```

The goal of my program is I have to calculate the SUM of the results in Row and Column direction. If the result is a 0, the course cannot have any effect on the sum of the row or column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asuming that the columns in the file are separated by spaces, then you could do this:

```
import pandas as pd

index_list = []
result_list = []
with open("resultaten.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line) > 0:
            num, name, vak1, vak2, vak3, vak4, vak5 = line.split()
            index_list.append(num)
            result_list.append([vak1, vak2, vak3, vak4, vak5])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=result_list,
    index=index_list,
    columns=['vak1', 'vak2', 'vak3', 'vak4', 'vak5'])

# the sum of each column
df.sum(axis=0)

# the sum of each row
df.sum(axis=1)
```

This uses a `pandas.DataFrame` to make easy calculations afterwards.

Comment: If you're going introduce pandas into this - why not just start with `df = pd.read_table('somefile.txt', sep=' ', index_col='nummer')` ?

Comment: Oh, nice, today I learned that there is a function [`pd.read_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html#pandas-read-table). Thanks, @JonClements

Comment: I get the following error code:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\migue\OneDrive\Zuyd\Leerjaar 1\Logica\PI4_Deel2\PI4_Deel2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'   ... I am sorry but my knowledde is very basic so I do not know how to fix this.

Comment: `pandas` is an external lib. You need to install it first, `pip3 install pandas`